# FFMpeg can't concat certain videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, concatenation

I have some videos recorded with my android phone. They are quite similar. For instance:

- [original0.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjZWRlc0tveThiZ2s)
- [original1.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjbnVYNkRoSjg1bVU)
- [original2.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjNTV4eGJRUFFrbVU) (*this one is broken*)

I apply this filter to each of them:

```
ffmpeg -i original0.mp4 -filter_complex "crop=720:720:280:0, scale=640:640, transpose=1" -threads 3 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -y processed0.mp4`
```

Results:

- [processed0.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjQWFlRzFtQk4wemM)
- [processed1.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjbVV1ZlMwbDdxZFk)
- [processed2.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjZkxpLUJOZkhaVVU) (*this one is broken*)

Resulting videos are ok. Then I want to concat them in different combinations, like: `original0 -> original1 -> original2`, `original1 -> original0 -> original2` and so on. I use this command for it:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i tmp.txt -codec copy -threads 3 -strict -2 -y combination.mp4
```

Any combinations of `processed0.mp4` and `processed1.mp4` work fine. But if I include `processed2.mp4` to combination - the resulting video is broken:

- [combination.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb8d9xvN0SjNkZhVzMyaGFPODQ) (`proccesed0 -> processed1 -> processed2`)

All videos are recorded in the same way at intervals of several seconds and the same combination of original videos works good. So I'm wondering what's wrong with `original2` or `processed2` and how to fix it? Perhaps I need to add some flags when applying filters? My guess is that it happens because of timestamps.

Comment: Have you tried `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS` in your filter graph to rule out timestamp issues?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck, I haven't. I tried to rewrite filter to this `crop=720:720:280:0, scale=640:640, transpose=1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS`. But it looks like I have to specify some mappings to filter audio and video simultaneously. And I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

Your inputs vary in frame rates (refer to the `ffmpeg` console outputs), and I believe the MP4 muxer does not support variable frame rates.

## A few solutions

You can either:

- use a different container format, such as Matroska (.mkv), for both the processed files and final output, or
- add the `fps` filter to your filtergraphs to give each processed file a common frame rate:

  ```
  -filter_complex "crop=720:720:280:0, scale=640:640, transpose=1, fps=30"
  ```

---

## Other junk

- `-threads 3` and `-strict -2` do nothing when stream copying (`-c copy`).
- libx264, the H.264 encoder, automatically calculates the optimal number of threads by default, so forcing a specific value may be suboptimal.
- If you choose to output to MP4, then consider adding `-movflags +faststart` to your final output command. It is helpful when viewing via progressive download; otherwise the whole file must be completely downloaded before playback can begin.
- In a comment you mentioned filtering audio and video separately. A simple example may help:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]hflip,negate[bg]; \
   [1:v]vflip,hue=s=0,scale=120:-1[fg]; \
   [bg][fg]overlay[v]; \
   [0:a]aphaser,flanger[a]" \
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
  ```

Comment: I added "fps=30" to the filter-graph and now it works! Thanks!!!